# Selenium driver.get() having inconsistent performances

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

In my function, I am using `driver.get(url)`, taking the `page_source` of the url and returning it as a bs4 element. I call this function mutliple times in a loop to scrape multiple webpages.
However I am noticing inconsistent performances everytime I run the loop. It gets stuck on different webpages, for anywhere between 20min to 1hr, before I manually stop the code entirely.

What is causing the `driver.get()` statement to get stuck inconsistently?

I am using chrome version 115.0.5790.171, selenium 4.10.0 and python 3.11.4

The webpage seems to load fine. I have `set_page_load_timeout(60)`, `implicitly_wait(60)` but they are unable to detect when the `driver.get()` function exceeds its set time. I have attached a simplified version of my code.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.set_page_load_timeout(60)
driver.implicitly_wait(60)
    
def get_bs4_element(url):
    try:
        driver.get(url)
        html = driver.page_source
        return BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    except WebDriverException as e:
        print("Selenium encountered an exception:", str(e))
```

I am new to using selenium, so I may have overlooked something obvious.

Answer (score 0):

your code is utilizing multiprocessing to run driver.get(url) in a separate process and then waiting for a certain time before proceeding. However, there are a few potential issues in your implementation that might be causing inconsistent performance or getting stuck. such as:

- In the **Process** constructor, you should pass the function
  **driver.get** as the target argument and provide the **URL** as an argument to the **args** parameter. Here's how you should modify the
  process creation:

```
process = multiprocessing.Process(target=driver.get, args=(url,))
```

- Side Note: the **driver.get** method itself is not designed to run in a separate
  process using multiprocessing. It interacts with the web browser, and
  using it in a separate process can lead to unexpected behavior and
  inconsistencies.

Instead of multiprocessing, I'll advice using threads with the **ThreadPoolExecutor** from the **concurrent.futures** module. Threads are generally more suitable for I/O-bound tasks like web scraping.

Here's an example of how I could modify your code using **ThreadPoolExecutor:**

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import WebDriverException, TimeoutException
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.set_page_load_timeout(60)
driver.implicitly_wait(60)

def get_bs4_element(url):
    try:
        driver.get(url)
        html = driver.page_source
        return BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    except WebDriverException as e:
        print("Selenium encountered an exception:", str(e))

urls = [...]  # List of URLs to scrape

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
    results = executor.map(get_bs4_element, urls)

# Process the results as needed
for result in results:
    if result:
        # Process the BeautifulSoup element
        pass
```

Comment: my apologies, i realize after rereading my question that it was misleading. i encountered inconsistent performance with selenium driver.get(). When scraping multiple websites, it randomly "gets stuck" and it seems to remain stuck for over an hour. I'm wondering if I am not using selenium correctly, and what might be causing the webdriver to get stuck? Since I do not know the cause, I am currently trying to make it throw an error. That being said, thank you for letting me know about ThreadPooling. I will try to implement this.

Comment: All good! You're using driver.get() correctly.  Inconsistent performance and getting stuck while using driver.get() in Selenium could be caused by various factors. Here are some common reasons and potential solutions. such as: 1. Network Issues. 2) Page Complexity: Some websites have complex structures with heavy JavaScript and dynamic content loading. If the page takes a long time to load or heavily relies on JavaScript execution, it might lead to driver.get() taking longer than expected. etc...

Comment: I will advise running your script with only 1 url in the urls list and slowly increase the url. If your code work perfectly with only one url but get stuck with two url try using selenium tearDown() method. If that doesn't  work. I will run your code tonight and share a GitHub link with you.

Comment: If you need to understand what's happen underneath the hood when you call your function. please watch this video on YouTube, skip to 5:18. don't worry about the code in the video. focus on how application memory work once you run your program: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CpjVucvAc3g&list=PL2_aWCzGMAwLZp6LMUKI3cc7pgGsasm2_&index=7

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have implemented ThreadPoolExecutor, and made changes so the driver is always scraping one url at a time. Additionally, I added a timeout for the executor, similar to how I did it with multiprocessing. However, I am still encountering the same issue: the driver is still getting stuck. My current goal is to simply detect when the driver gets stuck, but I have found no solutions so far. I am surprised that timeouts in multiprocessing or threads can't detect the driver getting stuck.

Comment: I am working with a pretty good computer and a very stable and fast network, so I assume it isn't network issues. Since the driver is taking over an hour, it doesn't seem likely that it is page complexity. I would assume a complex page may take up to a few minutes, but not an hour.

Comment: here is a link to YouTube of me running your code: https://www.youtube.com/shorts/-sFidESWsFA

Here is a GitHub link to the code: 
https://github.com/mosesmccabe/Selenium-Q-A/tree/master